# How to check Google Calendar to see if event already exists before adding

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-calendar-api

There's a website that has scheduled events that I've been able to pull down the information, parse it, and put it on my personal Google calendar. Before I add an event to Google calendar, I want to check to see if there is an event with that same title and time already in my Google calendar. If yes, skip that event. If no, post it.

My thinking is that I grab all the dates starting from today and get the next X number of events, like how it does in Google's own [Quickstart tutorial](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python). Then, with each potentially new event, check to see if it matches the date, time, and description of an event that is already in the calendar.

Here's what I have that I thought would work, but doesn't [EDITED TO UPDATE THE CODE]:

Now it doesn't post any events, even if the time isn't filled.

```
        new_event = {
            'summary': event_summary,
            'location': event_location,
            'description': '',
            'start': {
                'dateTime': event_start,
                'timeZone': 'America/Chicago',
            },
            'end': {
                'dateTime': event_end,
                'timeZone': 'America/Chicago',
            },
            'reminders': {
                'useDefault': True,
            },


        }

        now = datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'  # 'Z' indicates UTC time

        events_result = service.events().list(calendarId=calendar_ID,
                                              timeMin=now,
                                              maxResults=50, singleEvents=True,
                                              orderBy='startTime').execute()
        events = events_result.get('items', [])

        for event in events:
            start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
            summary = event['summary']

            if start == event_start and summary == event_summary:
                break
            else:
                service.events().insert(calendarId=calendar_ID, body=new_event).execute()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I'm self taught so my knowledge and ability is limited.

Comment: Any error messages you see?

Comment: Can you specify what doesn't work.  Is your query erroring?  Is it not finding any calendar events? Is it finding events but your dedup script isn't working?  Is the dedup working but your post to create new events failing? Is the post seeming to succeed but when you check the calendar there are no new events?

Comment: We'll probably move this comments section to a chat but let's see how far we can get here.
1. Thanks for updating the code.
2. You're aiming to produce a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example.  Please read this before continuing : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
3. In your case I'd start stripping down your code to just get the insert working again.  If this doesn't work, then post _*all*_ of that stripped down code minus any security / secrete tokens.  I think you should be aiming for about 4 lines maximum.  i.e. `from googlelibrarything import serviceCreator` [...cont]

Comment: [...cont] `service = serviceCreator("your id", "your secret"); new_event = {'summary': "some event summary", ... etc ...}; service.events().insert(calendarId="calendar ID", body=new_event).execute()`
4. If that works then I'd recommend putting some `print()` statements in.  For example, what does `print(start, event_start, start == event_start, summary, event_summary, summary == event_summary)` show?

Comment: 5.  Also are you sure that `events` is even coming back with anything apart from an empty array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work it out with a little help:

using:

```
 new_event = {
            'summary': event_summary,
            'location': event_location,
            'description': '',
            'start': {
                'dateTime': event_start,
                'timeZone': 'America/Chicago',
            },
            'end': {
                'dateTime': event_end,
                'timeZone': 'America/Chicago',
            },
            'reminders': {
                'useDefault': True,
            },

        }
```

this is the code:

```
class PostToGoogleCalendar:
def __init__(self):
    self.creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            self.creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not self.creds or not self.creds.valid:
        if self.creds and self.creds.expired and self.creds.refresh_token:
            self.creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            self.creds = flow.run_local_server()
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(self.creds, token)

    self.service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=self.creds)

def get_events(self):
    now = datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'
    events_result = self.service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                               maxResults=500, singleEvents=True,
                                               orderBy='startTime').execute()
    return events_result.get('items', [])

def create_event(self, new_event):
    if not self.already_exists(new_event):
        event = self.service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=new_event).execute()
        return event.get('htmlLink')
    else:
        return 'Event Already Exists'

def already_exists(self, new_event):
    events = self.get_date_events(new_event['start']['dateTime'], self.get_events())
    event_list = [new_event['summary'] for new_event in events]
    if new_event['summary'] not in event_list:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def get_date_events(self, date, events):
    lst = []
    date = date
    for event in events:
        if event.get('start').get('dateTime'):
            d1 = event['start']['dateTime']
            if d1 == date:
                lst.append(event)
    return lst
```